# How to apply color for underline style in NSAttributedString (ios)?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

Let's say i'm adding underline style in NSAttributedString:

```
[attrStr addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) range:range];
```

Is it possible to apply color (not only underline style) to underline without changing text color?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILabel: Custom underline color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419945/uilabel-custom-underline-color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Use `NSUnderlineColorAttributeName` to set the underline color.

```
[attrStr addAttribute:NSUnderlineColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:range];
```